# Quarternions and rotation

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, euler-angles

Hello I 'm getting from my embedded device Quarternions which I plot.
And my problem is when I 'm rotating it by 360 degrees, I'm not getting the same points as the starting position, but when I rotate it 720 degress I'm getting the starting position.
I m not sure how Quarternions are represented, or is something wrong, and is there way to fix it?

this is the starting position when it is rest on the table.
[image]

If I rotate the device 360 degress in one direction this is what I'm getting
[image]

720 degress rotation seems to have the same postition as the starting point
[image]

Comment: Ha-ha-ha-ha-ha, you discovered double cover! https://www.gathering4gardner.org/g4g13gift/math/BickfordNeil-GiftExchange-WhyDoTheUnitQuaternionsDoubleCoverTheSpaceOfRotations-G4G13.pdf

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux So Is this ok, or is something wrong with my data.

Comment: No, this is ok, I believe. Read the paper and search for rotation double-cover